# Exchange Sort Algorithm query

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

So I have tried to make this algorithm to work but everytime I run it I get [10,11,7,10,7,5,7,5 ] as my output. The goal was to get results in descending order. Furthermore I do not understand why there are 8 results when my array only contains 6 values. Please Help.. Thank you.
public class searches {

```
public static void main (String[]args)
{
    int[] array = {10,7,11,5,13,8};
    //ExchangeSort(array);

};

public static void ExchangeSort(int[] num)
{
    int i,j,temp;

    for(i=1;i<num.length-1;i++)
    {
        for(j=i+1;j<num.length;j++)
        {
            if(num[i]<num[j])
            {
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;

                //System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }

    }
};
```

};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are ignoring first element in sorting as array index start from `0`. Your first loop should start with index `0` and go up to `length-1` as:

```
     for(i=0;i<num.length-1;i++)
```

Also you need to print the sorted array outside the loops or in the main method using `Arrays.toString` **(no loop required)** as:

```
     // this will print the array elements
     System.out.println("Sorted Array: "+Arrays.toString(num));
```

and remove the semicolons `;` from the end of the methods.

Observatory Note: You method name shouldn't start with Upper Case letter.

EDIT: Your full corrected code is as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {10,7,11,5,13,8};
    exchangeSort(array);
    System.out.println("Sorted Array: "+Arrays.toString(array));
}
public static void exchangeSort(int[] num) {
    int temp;
    for(int i=0;i<num.length-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<num.length;j++){
            if(num[i]<num[j]){
                temp = num[i];
                num[i] = num[j];
                num[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Sorted Array: "+Arrays.toString(num));
}
```

Comment: @user1883386: Just an FYI, I updated the answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Where comes your output from?

I removed the comments before `ExchangeSort(array);` and added a simple output:

```
    ExchangeSort(array);

    for (int i : array) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
```

When I then run your code I get: `10 13 11 8 7 5` which is close to the expected result. The `10` is at the wrong position because your loop index starts with 1 but array indices start with 0. So the first element will not be changed.

You can fix this with changing the start value of `i` from `1` to `0`:

```
for(i=0; i<num.length-1; i++)
```